# Cannot login to chat.meta.stackexchange.com; server error when trying to access chat homepage

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, login, 500-server-error

I just recreated my MSE account after having deleted it a few years ago. Now, I'm trying to log in to Meta Stack Exchange Chat, and whenever I try to do so, it just fails silently and I'm still logged out.

Additionally, in the same browser session that I'm supposedly logged out, I get a server error when accessing the chat homepage or the chat profile page of any user. I don't get any errors when trying to access any of these pages in a private session. I also was able to sign in to Stack Exchange Chat and Stack Overflow Chat without problems, since my accounts on SO and my parent site for SE chat haven't been deleted.

I think it might be because it's trying to sign me in to my old chat profile, which was not deleted, but that is associated to my old, deleted site account, which clash and thus cause it to fail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you suspected, there was an old chat profile hanging around, attached to your account but referencing a user profile that no longer exists.

I deleted it; you should be able to log in fresh now.

[For a bit over a year now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283431/how-does-one-delete-a-chat-profile/283432#283432), we've been automatically deleting chat profiles when the last associated parent profile is deleted; this should avoid such problems in the future.

If you suspect you may be encountering the same problem, please [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and we'll fix it for you.