# Log in to MSE Chat seems broken

Tags: support, chat, login

Does someone know if the login's system for the chat is somehow broken? The link  chat.meta.stackexchange.com gives me an error page.

[image]

If I try to bypass that error and go to the Tavern chat room directly, I get asked to add a login method to my account, as illustrated there;

[image]

And if I click **To continue without adding a new way to log in, click here**, the system opens the chat room and tell me I'm not logged in. *I can't login, as if I click login again I'm still asked to add a log in method.*

[image]

Comment: Are you suspended from chat? Did you merge accounts somewhere in the past? Did it ever work?

Comment: @rene I never joined those chat room before on MSE, but I can join SF's chat room, where I was active.I got one account deleted in the past at my request, but no ban or suspension.

Comment: MSE, SO and SE are separate chatservers, with their own user account. In previous cases where I have seen this go wrong an old chat account got hooked up somehow. Needs Adam Lear or at least SE staff to fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had an ancient chat profile hanging around, one that was attached to a main-site profile that you'd deleted a while back.

I've removed this profile (which you'd never really used anyway). You should be able to access chat on MSE now.

Comment: How do these profiles stick around like this?

Comment: We didn't used to delete them automatically, @Pheo. So anyone who deleted their main-site account after entering chat prior to $fixdate$ would be unable to use chat if they later rejoined the site.

Comment: This problem is the [exact same problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304241/cannot-login-to-chat-meta-stackexchange-com-server-error-when-trying-to-access) I faced a while back. I edited your answer with instructions to contact the team if one encounters the same problem, so that 1. the site isn't cluttered with questions that aren't really useful to others, and 2. it can be used as a duplicate target.

Comment: @SonicWizard you linked to wrong contact, the magic link you tried to use is not for the contact form.