# Not able to login to chat.stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, support, chat, login, user-accounts

I have an account in `stackoverflow.com`, today I tried to join a chat room for some technical discussion and help. But I am not able to login to it. `chat.stackoverflow.com` is throwing `"Something bad happened error"` and If I directly click the link to join the chat room. It is showing that I need to be login to chat, but I am already logged in. I don't unerstand why it is happening to my account. Any solution for this?

Comment: Did you by any chance delete your account and then later rejoin the site? See [Cannot login to chat.meta.stackexchange.com; server error when trying to access chat homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304241/cannot-login-to-chat-meta-stackexchange-com-server-error-when-trying-to-access)

Comment: No. I had used two accounts long back ( 3 years back). Because one of them blocked for some reason( Dont remember exactly why). from then, I am using this sccount only. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: For the record, using a second account to escape a ban on the first one is forbidden. Just sayin'... Dunno if it's related.

Comment: @Jenayah The error in this case means that their new account is still linked to their old chat profile, which means the system knows that it's still the same user, and as such any bans would have been automatically reinstated.

Comment: @Sonic this got nothing to do with bans. Old chat profiles are not accessible and throwing errors.

Comment: Is there anything I can do  to solve this?

Comment: @Naroju I've deleted the chat profile that your SO account was associated with - if you try and join SO chat again it should work...

Comment: @JonClements  Thanks. It is working now