# Can't chat in MSE chat

Tags: bug, chat, login, 500-server-error

I can't chat on [chat.meta.stackexchange.com](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com). Sometimes it shows [this page](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/):

[image: Error page on chat.meta.stackexchange.com]

When looking into console, it shows 500 status code error:

[image: Console showing 500 status code]

And sometimes I am simply not logged in chat (however on MSE I am logged in successfully):

[image: an image showing the "log in" button]

This may be related to the recent events (a bug happened and some of the accounts got merged randomly, including mine).

However the other chat servers (SO and general SE) are fine.

Comment: It's the same issue as [Cannot login to chat.meta.stackexchange.com; server error when trying to access chat homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304241/cannot-login-to-chat-meta-stackexchange-com-server-error-when-trying-to-access). The main site profile ID in your chat profile is a different ID. The only way to get this fixed is to contact SE as mentioned there.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I've seen your question. Directly it does not answer my question. I have created my own question in order to have it fixed for my account. Also, the answer is said that "..., should avoid such problems in the future", but no, it doesn't. So, Tl;DR: it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Also I have contacted SE a month ago when I got merged with a random user. They did fix the main profiles, but did not fix the chat profiles.

Comment: It was most likely just missed since you likely didn't mention it in your contact request - it gets hard if your chat profile has 1,000+ messages. Also, there's past case precedent for similar cases of issues where the answer was a staff member posting "Okay, I fixed it for you" as an answer: someone posted an intentional duplicate, and while staff did fix it, they then closed it as a duplicate themselves since the root cause was the exact same and instructed users to contact them if they got the same issue. (The post is deleted now so I can't find it.)

Comment: This is an account issue. To get account issues fixed, you **need** to use the "Contact"/"Contact Us" link in the footer of every page on the site. Posting on MSE or MSO isn't effective for *account* issues that require someone to fix things, as only SE staff can do that, and they don't monitor meta sites for problems. Given that it's chat, an MSE moderator *may* be able to refresh your chat profile from MSE, but, given the state your account was in, might result in all of your prior chat messages being lost or not recovered.

Comment: @Makyen Given that the answer there explicitly states to contact SE if one experiences the same problem, this is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: In your Contact Us, you might want to mention that your prior messages on chat.SO have not been re-connected with your account. Basically, [your old chat.SO account](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/21493925/petid-csc) still exists and is the owner for all your messages. Your [new chat.SO account](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/23531430) only has the message which you sent today. That appears to also be the case on chat.SE.

Comment: @Makyen Got it, thanks. It's just weird they didn't fix it (given that I have contacted them recently with the random merge issue and they reinstated my accounts, but did not fix my chat account).