# Chat parent user doesn't reflect deleted account

Tags: bug, chat, deleted-accounts, parent-user

Parent user for [chat user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/203841/) is deleted, but chat user page displays him like existing one:

> [image: chat user]

Name, reputation and badges are still visible, but [parent user](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/207618/hades) is deleted.

According to Shog9's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283432/339911) chat user should be deleted, but it doesn't. Hence proposed duplicates are not duplicates, because doesn't answer my question.

Comment: To this day, chat profile is independent entity. Deleting an account never deleted the associated chat profile, so I'm sure it's not a bug. SE staff (maybe mod is enough) must go and manually delete the chat profile.

Comment: (dupe proves this is by design.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard but you still don't have a [bug] dupe-hammer :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard balpha is refering to somekind of *planned improvements*, so this maybe **-planned** instead of **-by-design**.

Comment: hehehe... omg... well, umm... sorry. *cough*. Well, you should know better than most people what status-planned means. (hint: not what it implies)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I would prefer [status-planned] here by employee (don't offer me a regular diamond mod) instead of closing as a duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard BTW It will look weird for me if [bug] question will be closed as a duplicate of [support] question.

Comment: Well, employees retag bugs to support many times, we can use SEDE to get actual numbers, but I've seen it a lot, so a bug closed as dupe of support just means it's by design. And in case I'm wrong, employee can always reopen (if it's closed), and tag properly.

Comment: Also note that this can also occur in case *all* of the user's site profiles were deleted prior to a 2016 change to automatically delete chat profiles in that case. See [How does one delete a chat profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283431/how-does-one-delete-a-chat-profile)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog if I understand Shog9's answer correctly we need to know is there any user account on some SE sites or not. If the latter then - it's a bug.If the first - it's by-design?

Comment: @Shadow Afaik chat profiles do now get deleted if all other profiles are deleted, but only if they've posted less than 1,000 messages. Accounts with more than that require manual intervention (even moderators and regular staff like me cannot delete chat profiles with more messages than that, only developers).

Comment: @animuson oh, I see. Still, there is no bug here, so my original claim still holds. :)

Comment: @animuson is there an answer about 1000+ chat messages? Would you to post an answer here instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As animuson [says in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319487/chat-parent-user-doesnt-reflect-deleted-account#comment1046866_319487), if a user posted more than 1000 messages in chat, their chat profile will not get automatically deleted when their parent account (and even all of their SE accounts) is deleted.

This is by design, and it requires manual intervention of a developer to have such chat profiles deleted, i.e. even moderators and Stack Exchange "ordinary" staff can't do it.

Comment: Is this also the case for account mergers? This can also leave an orphaned chat user.

Comment: @Luuklag I'm not sure, any example of chat profile without parent with less than 1000 messages?

Comment: I don't know, only now that a regular at the Tavern has an orphaned chat profile, which was caused [by a merger](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=8592685#8592685).

Comment: @Luuklag Yes, it is the case for those too, as confirmed by [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283432/377214): no chat profiles will be affected on account mergers.