# What privileges and tools do Stack Exchange developers (not merely staff) have access to?

Tags: support, status-declined, privileges, stack-exchange-team

In the spirit of [What privileges and tools do staff members without a diamond have access to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344146/what-privileges-and-tools-do-staff-members-without-a-diamond-have-access-to/), I'd like to ask a similar question, but for users with the *developer* bit specifically (not just the general *staff* bit).

I've seen several cases where Stack Exchange staff members have migrated posts to other sites even if they are older than 60 days, or re-migrate posts that have already been migrated from another site to a third site, both scenarios which are blocked from moderator use.

Initially I assumed that any staff member with moderator rights can do so, but I just received [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344146/what-privileges-and-tools-do-staff-members-without-a-diamond-have-access-to/#comment1153448_344161) from an employee that states that it's not possible:

> [Those] special migration scenarios are closed to employees. [...] Have dev routes for it if necessary.

Additionally, it's been [commented before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319487/chat-parent-user-doesnt-reflect-deleted-account?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1046866_319487) that only *developers* specifically (and not just staff in general) can delete chat profiles that have posted 1,000 or more messages:

> [Chat] profiles do now get deleted if all other profiles are deleted, but only if they've posted less than 1,000 messages. Accounts with more than that require manual intervention (**even moderators and regular staff like me cannot delete chat profiles with more messages than that, *only developers***).

Given these, what privileges and tools do *developers specifically* have, in addition to the rights granted to staff members?

To be clear here, I'm only referring to *proper buttons* (in a GUI) that developers can press; manually editing the database or changing the code are excluded for obvious reasons (those can theoretically grant an infinite number of privileges). This exclusion also means that things like [manually triggering server errors to add multiple duplicate targets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289395/too-many-shogs-when-viewing-the-close-reason-in-the-ios-app#comment939289_289395) aren't included.

Comment: I would anticipate that developers have *no* proper buttons for Developer-only features.  Developers can edit the database or change the code, why would they need any lesser privileges?

Comment: @Brilliand As a convenience feature, perhaps?

Comment: @Brilliand Well... you'd be wrong. :P We actually do have tooling for some things that's dev-only, particularly things like site settings.

Comment: I ... get the curiosity, but let's be real for a second - nobody is going to sit down and enumerate every feature and route here to begin with, nevermind attempting to keep it maintained. Aside from that taking time that's better spent on actual dev work, it could potentially open up attack vectors. Not that we practice security by obscurity, but why invite trouble where there is none?

Comment: @AdamLear All of the examples I've mentioned above, as well as placing sites in read-only mode (something which I thought of after making this post), are fairly innocuous things. The point of this post is the same as the point of the previous post: sometimes, users see staff do things that they clearly can't do with their current reputation or lack of moderator rights, and there are some dev interactions that aren't on the list of things that staff can do that people see relatively often on the sites (e.g. migration over 60 days later). I'd like to have a similar documentation.

Comment: There’s a huge difference between those two questions. If you’re going from the angle of “that normal users can do with sufficient privilege”, that’d be a very different question! I think that’s at least part of the the concern @AdamLear has. The devs can do many things but they aren’t things users can do, too, so it’s unlikely to cause confusion if someone sees it... because they probably won’t notice.

Comment: As Adam said, the number of dev privileges are too many to enumerate, and we cannot do so for security reasons. There are over 2000 functions in the system that are only accessible to devs, as well as other privileges on the site which we are not going to list. That said, I want to make it clear that we try very hard to avoid ever editing the db directly. Too easy for things to go wrong, isn't reusable, hard for others to review, no audit trail. We use dev functions (and other tools) to perform those types of tasks, as well as other site maintenance functions.

Comment: @Catija Knowing that the ability to migrate posts that are more than 60 days old requires developer intervention and not just general staff intervention makes me less likely to ping the wrong person, or more likely to know that a contact request will take longer, if there is an exceptional case that requires me to request it.

Comment: ... but ability to migrate is a user tool, just not the older posts part. But this question potentially encompasses all sorts of things like making someone a moderator, running elections, disassociating posts and changing or creating help center pages, which are not things that users can do. Anyway, if you have specific questions like that, ask them rather than asking a hugely broad question.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog In almost all cases, users shouldn't really be asking for devs to do things that only they can do, anyways. Sure, sometimes those tools may be necessary, but making them more public (including ones like your example: migrating old posts) seems to create extra work. If there is a strong need for others to be able to do things that they cannot that should be a requested feature.