# Do we need any [developers] on Meta?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [developers](/questions/tagged/developers) tag has 11 questions but no tag excerpt. I see it's being used for questions about Stack Exchange's developers, for which we already have the [stack-exchange-team](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-team) tag, for [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s which (obviously) need a Stack Exchange developer to solve them, or questions which are relevant for users on the Stack Exchange who call themselves developers, but those usually belong on Meta Stack Overflow, not here.

Any thoughts or should we proceed to burninate?

Comment: I thought the policy was to test if the developers weigh as much as a duck first.

Comment: My sister was bitten by a developer.

Comment: @RobertColumbia my sister once bit a developer (me, to be precise ...) I can't remember if it was 8-bit or 16-bit though.

Comment: Not entirely sure if SE still shoots film.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the assistance of @Spevacus, a mod (necessary for the locked post) and a few others, the [developers](/questions/tagged/developers) tag has been removed from the list of questions on MSE (and indeed [all of Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdevelopers%5D)), and will be given to the flames of Trogdor within 24 hours.  I do hope this doesn't mean we'll find the bodies of several [developers](/questions/tagged/developers) across Meta within those 24 hours.

[image]

Comment: My hair's a little singed but I made it out okay

Comment: @KylePollard I've not heard from any of the others, so I assume they're all burninated?

Answer (score 14):

This tag doesn't really seem to fill a specific purpose at the moment.

The first question tagged with it is [this very old (and closed) question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16137/622284) (and is now historically locked, thanks mods!), which isn't even necessarily about SE Devs, but rather about famous developers who happen to use Stack Overflow. In most other cases, the tag is used where [stack-exchange-team](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-team) fits perfectly (or is [already there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344257/622284)).

With [developers](/questions/tagged/developers) sporting a measly 11 questions, and the most feasible topic for it to cover being SE Developers, which as mentioned is already covered by a tag, burnination seems like an acceptable solution here. Bring forth Trogdor!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with OP to burninate the tag. There's now only 10 questions with the tag, and two are closed.

When a developer is needed for a bug, the bug tag can be used, and when the question is just about "developers", it seems other tags are sufficient and it's not so important for a separate "developers" tag to exist.